# temporarily reset system date with applescript or shell

Tags: applescript

is there a way to temporarily reset the system date (Mountain Lion) with a script?

My idea would be of a script that reset the system to a chosen date/time (and disable the automatic synchronization).
And, maybe, a second script that re-select the checkbox 'set date and time automatically' ( but this of course can be easily done manually…)

Answer (score 1):

Use the -setdate or -settime options for systemsetup:

```
systemsetup -setusingnetworktime off -setdate 12:31:2013 -settime 23:59:59
```

Without `-setusingnetworktime off` there was an error like this:

> setDate: Error, you cannot set the date while network time is running. Use '-setusingnetworktime' to turn network time off.

This restores setting date and time automatically:

```
systemsetup -setusingnetworktime on
```

Comment: thank you very much,
beautiful little piece of code. It works - almost- like a charm… because I have to stop the script manually.
The little cog (in the status bar) that appears when an automator script is running, keeps on running until I select "stop the script [name]"…
Any idea?

Comment: Did you use a service that receives selected text as input and passes input to stdin? If you did, just change the input type to no input.

Comment: It was an application…  
Service:  Service receives: 'no input' in 'any application'
Run Shell Script (/bin/bash and to stdin) -- where I pasted your code    
(I tried also to check the button (in Options) 'Ignore this action's input'…)    
Both in Snow Leopard and Mountain Lion result is same: clog keeps on turning until I stop it.    
Further steps after 1st are not performed.    
I re-checked your code (for mistyping).    
The second script, the one that restores default behavior, works fine.

Comment: It works for me. It might be easier to use aliases or [history-search-backward](https://coderwall.com/p/oqtj8w) though.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it (about aliases and the history thingy)…
Just don't bother. I really appreciated the time you spent for me.
If the code works for you and not for me, the problem could be anywhere else.
And it's not such a big deal to stop manually the script.
Who knows, maybe one day I'll find it working and I won't know why…

many thanks again